# Android Emulator and VirtualBox not working with same settings

Tags: android-studio, windows-10, virtualbox, amd-processor

Is anyone able to get VirtualBox and Android Studio emulator work with same settings on Windows 10 & AMD A10-7850K?

Android Studio emulator works when

1. Windows Hypervisor Platform is `enabled` and
2. Hyper-V is `disabled` in 'Turn Windows features on and off'
3. bcdedit (cmd as Administrator) shows `hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto`

This on the other hand does not work with VirtualBox 6.0.4. When the above settings are active and I try to start virtual machine, I get prompt:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine WIN10 PRO 64-bit.

 (VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API).

AMD-V is not available (VERR_SVM_NO_SVM).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

In order to get the VirtualBox virtual machine to start I need to cmd:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

and restart. Now VirtualBox works, but Android Studio emulator does not start any virtual device. In order to get Android Studio emulator work I need to restore the hypervisorlaunchtype:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

and restart.

Which is quite annoying. Is there a way to overcome this?

```
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (Version   10.0.17763 Build 17763)
AMD A10-7850K Radeon R7, 12 Compute Cores 4C+8G, 3700 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
Android Studio 3.3.1
Android Emulator 28.0.23
VirtualBox 6.0.4 r128413 (Qt5.6.2)
```